# How to add a custom data source to an acf relationship field

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [webfacemedia.com](https://www.webfacemedia.com/stack-overflow/acf.png))</sub>

I have an acf relationship field that populates from the different post types of my wordpress site. In this particular use case, I want to add a custom data source to the drop down of post types..videos for example which get pulled from a 3rd party API. How do I go about adding this videos type to the list of dropdowns and formatting the videos data into something acf can understand and still process with the regular wordpress post types?

Comment: to add objects to this field, objects must have a unique identifier between all posts. then the easiest way to do that is to create a custom post type and to synchronise a video object in WordPress for each external video.